# About contradictory inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

We know that if $a,b,c≥0$

$a^3+b^3+c^3≥3abc$

> Let $abc=1$
>
> We get: $$a^3+b^3+c^3≥3$$

Then,

$a^3+b^3+c^3+(3abc)≥4\sqrt[4]{3}abc$

> And let $abc=1$
>
> We get:
>
> $$a^3+b^3+c^3≥4\sqrt[4]{3}-3$$

**Update:**

> For example: $a^3+b^3+c^3=4\sqrt[4]{3}-3+k$
>
> Here,
>
> if $0<k<6-4\sqrt[4]{3}$
>
> We get, $a^3+b^3+c^3<3$

A Contradiction?!
What is wrong?

Comment: Where did you get $k<6-4\sqrt[4]3$? That’s wrong, in fact $k\geqslant 6-4\sqrt[4]3$.

Comment: I'm trying to say the same thing, this is a contradiction.

Comment: I see no contradiction except your error in your statement of bounds on $k$.

Comment: @Macavity if $k=0.3$  $a^3+b^3+c^3=4 \sqrt [4]{3} -3+0.3$ you get contradiction.

Comment: But $k$ cannot be $0.3$. So no contradiction.

Comment: Why? According to second inequality can be..

Comment: Try finding any value of $a,b,c$ with $abc=1$ which gives such a $k$. Just because you have an Inequality like $3>2$ does not mean you can say $3=2+k$ and then set $k=0.3$ or some random number.

Comment: I do not know how to calculate this.

Answer (score 2):

Because in your AM-GM the equality occurs for the equality case of all variables,

but $3abc=a^3=b^3=c^3$ for positive variables gives

that in your last inequality the equality does not occur and it's indeed so.

We have no any contradiction.

If you want to use AM-GM for the second expression you can write the following.
$$a^3+b^3+c^3+3abc\geq6\sqrt[6]{a^3b^3c^3(abc)^3}=6abc,$$ which is very good, it's just Osem.

Comment: My explanation is the same. Read please my post. Since the equality does not occur you got $3>4\sqrt[3]3-3$, which is true. It's not contradiction!

Answer (score 1):

We do not have any contradiction here. One of the equation gives $a^3+b^3+c^3\ge 3$ and the other equation gives $a^3+b^3+c^3\ge ~2.2649$.

It would have been a contradiction if the signs were opposite.

Comment: I edited question

Comment: @MathLover I don't understand your question now. The limits of value on is supposed to imply what?

Comment: I edited again..@Aakhi Chatterjee

Comment: @MathLover Still does not matter. What you are trying to imply is since there is a limit on k, hence there is an upper limit. However, the upper limit on k is imposed by you. So, it does not mean anything.

Comment: You didn't understand me.

Comment: @MathLover Yes, it is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should evaluate $a^3,b^3,and\ c^3$ when $a=b=c=1$ to get a smallest possible value for the left side expression (because AM-GM inequality becomes equal when a=b=c, and in this case we have abc=1), and see that the inequality is alright.

$3\ge3$ and $3\ge\sqrt[4]{3}-3$ have no contradictions.